# Powermock without JUnit

Tags: java, powermockito

to extract some data from a legacy application, I currently use powermock to prepare a few quite-mangled-up classes and replace a few dependencies with mocks.

Thus, I have a JUnit test, which essentially does:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(LegacyDependency.class)
public class ThisIsNotReallyATest {
    @Test
    public void extractData() {
        ... prepare and wire mocks

        // new ClassUnderTest() will essentally call LegacyDependency.getInstance()
        Object result = new ClassUnderTest().doSomething();
        // save result for later reference
    }
}
```

Thus: this is NOT A TEST. This is a utility class which uses Powermock features to get around various badly modeled dependencies.

As using a test framework to create a utility which is not connected to unit testing whatsoever makes me feel real bad, the question is:

Can I use powermock (esp. the the PrepareForTest feature for static/final/etc.) in a standalone piece of software? If so: how?

Comment: You are misusing framework for something which was not designed for. If you have control over source code of legacy application, you should refactor it rather then doing this. Are you prepared for bytecode verification failures in production? (yes that's what powermock can bring you)

Comment: This is about a tool which is part of preparing the test-baseline for a coming refactoring. This is just for temporary use while cleaning up part of that mess.

Comment: It seems that you are just making use of the runtime bytecode replacement/generation in Powermock.  Why don't you simply make use of Javassist or ByteBuddy etc directly then?

Comment: This might be an option I have not looked at yet. Is this about as comfortable as powermockito?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the question is an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but

Let's say the constructor for `ClassUnderTest` is:

```
ClassUnderTest() {
    this.legacyDep = LegacyDependency.getInstance();
    // ...
}
```

And that you don't want some `LegacyDependency` behavior, 
you could do some refactoring like that:

```
// you can provide your own "LegacyDependency" that does nothing or something
ClassUnderTest(LegacyDependency legacyDep) {
    this.legacyDep = legacyDep;
    // ...
}

// old way
ClassUnderTest() {
    this(LegacyDependency.getInstance());
    // ...
}
```

Comment: No, this part of the question "how do I come from X to Y". What I did not mention initially is, that we are talking about a business-critical real-world application with roughly a millon lines of code. I'd *love* to refactor it, but I'd need a complete scrum team for about a year to do this. Right now, I just want to extract some data from a method, which cannot be called without the rest of the application being up and running under normal circumstances.

Comment: There's something odd here, if you can use Powermock to suppress some behavior, you can refactor as I said. So maybe you should edit your question and post some more "concrete" code.

Comment: Thank you for your attempt to tackle the problem from a different angle. Yes, refactoring would be possible, if I was willing to have a change encompassing about 200 changed constructor calls right now. I am not. This is about getting some baseline information to *prepare* a later refactoring. Thus: the object of observation *must not be changed* at this time. I'll just leave this comment sitting here for a while, before I delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @rkosegi's comment - you are misusing PowerMock for purpose for which it is not intended.

However, I understand your need to utilize PowerMock's cool reflection features. They are unfortunately very tightly coupled with testing framework features which you don't need. Since PowerMock runner initializes test environment in different classloader and tweaks some classes before putting them into this environment, you can mimic the PowerMock's work to do exactly the same, without need for test class, annotation etc.

In my [blog](http://tomaszalusky.blogspot.cz/2018/01/citelny-tostring-na-method-reference.html) (in Czech), I shown how to use Powermock's internals to get method name for given method reference. It was not as comfortable as Powermockito (actually it was very painful) but in retrospect you need just 1. reuse class loader, 2. implement class loader work (tweaking your `ClassUnderTest` in Javassist), 3. profit :-)

Anyway I warn you about production usage of such code, it's rather playing around.